# React - a way to unify, if many components have the same piece of code in lifecycle methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-lifecycle

I have multiple component with similar piece code in lifecycle methods and some similarity in state variables. Is there a way to unify them, by inheriting from one parent or something like that?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        //state properties similar in all components, getting from redux
        //state properties specific for this component
    }
    // same code in many components
}

componentWillMount() {
    // same code in many components
    // code specific for this component
}
```

Can I use children methods and props in parent "wrapper" ? Can I change component state from parent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create HOCs (Higher Order Components) in that case. It can look like this:

```
/*
   A Higher Order Component is a function,
   that takes a Component as Input and returns another Component.

   Every Component that gets wrapped by this HOC
   will receive `exampleProp`,`handleEvent`, 
   plus all other props that get passed in.
*/

function WithCommonLogic(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        example: ''
      }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
      ...
      // Same code in many components.
    }
    callback = () => {
      /* Enhanced components can access this callback 
         via a prop called `handleEvent`
         and thereby alter the state of their wrapper. */
      this.setState({example: 'some val'})
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent 
          exampleProp={this.state.example}
          handleEvent={this.callback}
          {...this.props}
      />
  }
}


// You use it like this:

const EnhancedComponent1 = WithCommonLogic(SomeComponent);
const EnhancedComponent2 = WithCommonLogic(SomeOtherComponent);
```

Now all the shared logic goes into that HOC, which then wrap all your different components you want to share it with.

See the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for further reading.

Comment: Can I use props from SomeComponent in WithCommonLogic wrapper?

Comment: No, but you can pass a callback function to the component as prop, and call whenever needed in a child to update something in the parent. I will update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You can create Higher Order Component (HOC) for that, basically, you just write component with your same lifecycle method which is repeating, and then in `render()` function, call `this.props.children` function with any HOC internal state arguments you want, you can pass the whole `state` and a `setState` function as well, so you can change the HOC's state inside the underlying component.

For example:

```
  class HOC extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     state = {
       someState: 'foo',
     };
   }

   componentWillMount() {
     console.log('i mounted!')
   }
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         {this.props.children({ state: this.state, setState: this.setState })}
       </div>
     )
   }
 }

 const SomeComponent = () =>
   <HOC>
     {({ state, setState }) => (
       <div>
         <span>someState value: </span>
         <input 
           value={state.someState} 
           onChange={e => setState({ someState: e.target.value})} 
         />
       </div>
     )}
   </HOC>
```

You can also do really cool and interesting things with it, like connecting a slice of your redux state whenever you need it:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ProfileState = connect(
  state => ({ profile: state.profile }),
  null,
)(({ 
  profile, 
  children
  }) => ( 
  <div>
    {children({ profile })}
  </div>
));

const ProfilePage = () => (
  <div>
    Your name is:
    <ProfileState>
     {({ profile }) => (
       <span>{profile.name}</span>
     )}
    </ProfileState>
  </div>
);
```

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) is the full documentation on this technique.

Comment: This is not really a HOC, this technique is called `render props`.

Comment: Thank you, and how SomeComponent can be look like if this is component with constructor, methods, render function... ?

Comment: @Jeremy you can convert functional component to stateful easily, just insert <HOC>{({ state, setState}) => 'anything'}</HOC> component in the returns of render function and you're done

Comment: ok..so this way I can't use setState from HOC inside lifecircle or other methods of SomeComponent, only directly in render, right ?

Comment: @Jeremy, oh you can easily route this setState to SomeComponent, in render function just call something like this.registerHOC({ state, setState }) which would be registerHOC = (({ state, setState }) => if (!this.HOCRegistered) { this.HOCSetState = setState; this.HOCState = state; this.HOCRegistered = true }